# How can I implement version control for documents in samba share?

Tags: server, samba, version-control, word-documents, document-management

I was wondering if there exists a way in which I can add version control ability to documents (only .txt or .docx) in a samba share. Basically, by version control, I imply that edits made by each user should be annotated with the author's name. Also, the changes can be retraced. I have searched but found no answer to even start with.

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: @Pilot6 The base server where the folders for shares are made has Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that's part of the Samba ([SMB](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block)) protocol.

File versioning should probably either be done on *document*, *filesystem* or *management* level.

There was a user-level versioning filesystem called [Wayback](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wayback/), but the project seems abandoned for 10 years.

The functionality you describe seems more like a feature of a Document Management System *(management level)* - so maybe you should look into such solutions.